# How to plot the average of a curve with seaborn?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I would like to plot the average of some points and their interval of confidence. I am using the seaborn. I tried to use regplot, the lmplot, but all of them do not work. This is my program:

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set_style("darkgrid")
sns.set(color_codes=True)

df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
print(df["a"])
sns.lineplot(y=df.a, x=df.index , data=df)
plt.ylabel("R")
plt.xlabel("T")
plt.show()
```

[image: img]

My goal is to get the red line in the figure. 
This is a simple of dataframe as saved in csv Fila

```
index     a
0      -0.120
1      -0.530
2      -0.250
3      -0.330
4      -0.560
5      -0.260
6       0.018
7       0.040
8      -0.460
9      -0.690
10     -0.130
11     -0.270
12     -0.080
13     -0.430
14     -0.170
15     -0.500
16     -0.690
17     -0.060
18     -0.200
19     -0.610
20     -0.370
21      0.090
22      0.190
23     -0.010
24      0.110
25     -0.250
26     -0.210
27     -0.160
28     -0.320
29      0.130
        ...  
2501    0.760
2502    0.690
2503    0.680
2504    0.750
2505    0.560
2506    0.570
2507    0.670
2508    0.800
2509    0.630
2510    0.570
2511    0.780
2512    0.800
2513    0.800
```

Comment: @vb_rises this is already what I use

Comment: what is the output of lineplot?

Comment: @vb_rises the output is the plot in the figure. It is important  to notice that I reduce the data length in my question to let the question be published

Comment: Can you clarify the question again. You said that output is the figure. In the question you says that you want redline in the output??

Comment: @vb_rises the output of my program id the plot without the red line. I add the red line and ask in stackoverflow the help to plot that red line. That means I need to plot the red line.

Comment: can you post sample data of `data.csv` as a dataframe?

Comment: @vb_rises, could you please check the question.

Answer (score 4):

Mean is an aggregattive function. It gets a few values and aggragates them into one.
In your case, since there is only one value per index, a mean aggragation will output a single value for the hole dataset, a single value cannot be plotted of course.
Therefore, Seaborn library plots an average line **Only when it needs to aggragate a few values per index**
In this case Seaborn will also provide you with a corresponding confidence interval.
An example for a command that would work:

**Dataset is appended as a picture**

[**Dataset**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGG5d.png)

when calling `sns.lineplot(y='Flights', x='Week' , data=df)`

Seaborn has to aggragate a few values for each week in order to plot the data. The default aggragation method is 'mean', so this aggragation will result at an average line with confidence interval.

**You can choose any Series aggragation method provided by Pandas, you can also write your own methods**